# How does iOS call delegates and datasource methods?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

For example, when we are creating tableview we need some datasource methods like

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messageArray.count
    }
```

I don't call this anywhere. However, iOS does this instead of me and I wonder how iOS does this?

iOS search for a tableview, if it is available on the view then call delegates and datasource methods or it called when we declare `uiTableView.delegate = self` or `uiTableView.datasource = self`. 
Another is these methods called before `viewDidLoad?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is the setup for a class with a delegate:

```
class SimpleTableView {
    var delegate: SimpleTableViewDelegate?
    // ...
    func renderCell(at row: Int) { // called whenever the table needs to render a cell
        let cell = SimpleTableViewCell()
        cell.frame.size.height = delegate?.tableView(self, cellHeightForRow: row)
        // continue rendering cell
    } 
}
```

The protocol `SimpleTableViewDelegate` contains the delegate methods. It would look something like this:

```
protocol SimpleTableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: SimpleTableView, cellHeightForRow: Int) -> CGFloat 
}
```

So what we have here is a class, `SimpleableView`, that gets data from somewhere (the view controller). This is how the delegate comes into play:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SimpleTableViewDelegate {
    var tableView = SimpleTableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: SimpleTableView, cellHeightForRow: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }
}
```

This is essentially how a delegate works, and that is what the real `tableView` is doing. You set the `tableView` delegate and `tableView` calls the delegate methods to get information from you.

Hopefully this helps explain to you how the delegate works here, what calls it, and what's going on in general. If you need clarification, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Thank you very much. So when I set  tableView.delegate = self, delegate is called right?

Comment: @John, delegate is just an object—a variable. When the tableView needs information from the view controller (like cell height) it calls the appropriate method on the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

So a quick way to look at this is separate these two things.

First lets look at delegate
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate

The delegate provides a set of methods that you can include in your code that provides a callback for uitableview to execute certain protocol defined methods depending on whats happening within the tableView.

example `func tableView(UITableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath)`

This example allows uitableview to ask you how should i display a certain cell at this current indexpath.

Next lets look at the datasource

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource

Datasource works in a similar fashion as the delegate but provides a different set of methods that help you populate your table view.

example `func numberOfSections(in: UITableView)`
Apple's uitableview will call this method and ask the tableview how many sections should I display.

Ultimately, these are just protocols that allow the tableview to interact with your code and helping you display your table with your configuration!

Answer (score 0):

`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` is method of the `UITableViewDatasource` protocol. The methods of data source are called by method `reloadData()` of `UITableView`.

According to documentation of `UITableView`:

> UITableView overrides the layoutSubviews() method of UIView so that it
>   calls reloadData() only when you create a new instance of UITableView
>   or when you assign a new data source. Reloading the table view clears
>   current state, including the current selection. However, if you
>   explicitly call reloadData(), it clears this state and any subsequent
>   direct or indirect call to layoutSubviews() does not trigger a reload.